# I am getting a promise object in the output of a flask app I am working on. How can I get the value from the promise object?

Tags: javascript

So basically, I am using fetch to get the data from my database. I wrote a few JS functions that will take effect once the user clicks on the like button. One of those functions will post the new data to the server (that is what it is intended to do later on but for now, I am just printing the output). The output from that function is a promise object that is being returned to the server in the form of a json object. How can I get my desired output which is the VALUE of that promise?

The JavaScript code:

```
            <script>
                const likebtn = document.getElementById('likebtn');
                const currentURL = window.location.href;
                const likenum = document.getElementById('likenumber');
                const postarray = currentURL.split("/");
                const postName = postarray[4];
                // console.log(postName)

                
    
                function setLikeBtnColor() {
                    likebtn.style.color = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('likebtn')) ? 'cornflowerblue':'black';
                }
            
                setLikeBtnColor();

                async function getlikenumber() {
                    const response1 = await fetch('/postlikes/'+postName)
                    fetchData = await response1.json()
                    likenum.textContent = fetchData.post_likes
                    return fetchData


                }
                async function getLikeNumber() {
                    const response = await fetch('/postlikes/'+postName)
                    fetchData = await response.json()
                    likenum.textContent = fetchData.post_likes
                    return fetchData
                }
                
                function myFunction() {
                    localStorage.setItem('likebtn', !JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('likebtn')));
                    setLikeBtnColor();
                    if (likebtn.style.color === 'cornflowerblue') {
                        let currentLikeNum = getLikeNumber()
                        fetch('/postlikes/'+postName, {
                            method:"POST",
                            body: JSON.stringify({
                                post_likes:currentLikeNum+1
                            }),
                            headers:{
                                "Content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8"
                            }

                        })
                        getlikenumber()

                    } else {
                        let currentLikeNum = getLikeNumber();
                        fetch('/postlikes/'+postName, {
                            method:"POST",
                            body: JSON.stringify({
                                post_likes:currentLikeNum
                            }),
                            headers:{
                                "Content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8"
                            }
                        })
                        getlikenumber()

                    }};
                likebtn.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
                getlikenumber()
                
    
            </script>
```

The python/flask code:

```
@app.route('/postlikes/<string:post_name>', methods=["GET","POST"])
def postlikes(post_name):
    if request.method == "GET":
        post = Image.query.filter_by(post_name=post_name).first()
        # return "{'post likes':" + "'" + str(post.likes) + "'}"
        return {"post_likes":post.likes}
    else:
        print(request.json)
```

My desired output:

```
{'post_likes':1}
```

or

```
{'post_likes':'1'}
```

the output I am getting:

```
{'post_likes': '[object Promise]1'}
```

P.S the initial value of the likes on the post_likes is 0.

Comment: These calls here `let currentLikeNum = getLikeNumber()` are asynchronous (they are marked with the `async` keyword), and since you don't await them, you see the promise. Either wrap all of it in an async method, and await it, or use the `then` method to complete the promise chain

Comment: You really should have a `/postlikes/<string:post_name>/increment` endpoint that you call once, instead of doing 3 server requests when the button is clicked!

Answer (score 1):

`getLikeNumber()` returns a promise because an `async function` always returns a promise.
The keyword `async` just makes your whole function one big promise that await other promises inside its body, crudely abstracted.

So when you write :

```js
    let currentLikeNum = getLikeNumber() // currentLikeNum is a promise return
    fetch('/postlikes/'+postName, {
      method:"POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
      post_likes:currentLikeNum+1  // currentLikeNum is a promise return converted to a string + "1"
```

So what you want is to either keep your function `myFunction` `async` and await your promise to keeps only the returns, like you already did with `getLikeNumber()`

Or with the old way :

```js
getLikeNumber().then( res => {
    //do your post here with the res variable
})
```

But that would not be consistent with your previous function.
In any case I would suggest to read one tutorial on async/await VS .then/.catch to continue your project comfortably.

Have a nice day !